# $lookup work in MongoDB but doenst work with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I have two Documents:

```
Category = new Schema({
  storeKey: { type: String, required: true },
  cod: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  visible: { type: Boolean }
},
  {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "created",
      updatedAt: "updated"
    }
  }

);
```

and:

```
Product = new Schema({
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        cod: String,
        storeKey: { type: String, required: true },
        categoryId: String,
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        stockQuantity: { type: Number, required: true },
        avatar: String,
        visible: Boolean
    }, {
            timestamps: true
        });
```

Query on server whith mongoose to locate products with the aggregate category

```
Product.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Category",
                localField: "categoryId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "category"
            }
        }]
    ).exec((error, done) => {
        if (error) res.status(500).send({
            message: langs[req.query.lang],
            error
        });

        res.status(200).send(done);
    });
```

query on local terminal

```
db.Product.aggregate(
        [{
            $lookup: {
                localField: "categoryId",
                from: "Category",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "category"
            }
        }])
```

In the terminal, $lookup works correctly. With mongoose, it brings duplicate records and does not bring existing categories. What is wrong?

Comment: `category` should be `categories` in from ??

Answer (score 0):

@Anthony Winzlet was correct, should be `categories` (in the pural) would have to leave `categories` (in the pural) and not `category`, but also, i had not defined the categoryId field as being an `ObjectId` in the Product Schema, so it was comparing string with `ObjectId`. In the tests in the terminal I had saved the server return, which returns the _id fields as strings. Now it's working.Thanks!

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    cod: String,
    storeKey: { type: String, required: true },
    categoryId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    stockQuantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    avatar: String,
    visible: Boolean
}, {
        timestamps: true
    });
```